# Orbits of a unipotent subgroup

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, linear-groups

Let $G$ be a connectd linear group which acts transitively on the space $X$. Let $U$ be a unipotent subgroup of $G$. How to prove that $U$-orbits are closed copies of $\mathbb C^k$ in $X$?

Comment: Are the $U$-orbits   homogeneous spaces under the action of $U$?